# Cannot create WebApplicationFactory in net 7 integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've followed the documentation for setting up integration tests in my net 7 solution. This worked fine in net 6, but now I'm getting an error (see below).

I've set up a new web api project, Program.cs exposes its class:

```
public partial class Program { }
```

My class library with tests and a sample test file:

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        private CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory = null!;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program> { }
```

Test project dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="7.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.4" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.4.0" />
```

When tring to instansiate `CustomWebApplicationFactory`

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies cannot be loaded for execution. (0x80131058)'

Has anything changed in order to make this work in net 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue using net 6. The issue might be in the latest version of `NUnit3TestAdapter` package. Downgrading to version 4.3.1 worked for me.

These GitHub issues might be related to the problem

- https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/1066
- https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/1065